# Sennheiser K6 making purring sound?

Tags: microphone, troubleshooting

I have this [ME66/K6](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/73100-REG/Sennheiser_ME66_K6_COMBO_ME66_K6_Super_Cardioid_Mic.html) combo mic. It randomly started making this [purring noise](https://soundcloud.com/michael-mcgreal-2/sennheiser-k6-noise).

I changed the XLR cable, audio interface, battery etc.. still nothing. However, After removing the ME66 portion, the purring remained... so I think I isolated it to the K6 battery pack portion. When the ME66 portion is on, it still records audio, but is heavily overpowered by the purring noise.

Has anyone experienced this or something similar?

Many thanks,
Michael